# Entity Framework code first SaveChanges throws SQL error on some servers but not others

Tags: c#, wpf, frameworks, entity, sybase

[image]

As the title says.

I run the program from my machine and it retrieves and saves data fine.  When I deploy the solution to our terminal servers the data WILL retrieve and load fine but any updates or inserts performed by calling SaveChanges throws the attached error.

I'm using EF5 code first approach to an exisiting sybase database.

I would understand if it didn't return any data AND didn't save but why would it return data and not save and why would it only be some machines.

the only thing I can see that is different is the OS versions.

works on:
windows 7
windows 8
windows server 2008

does not work on:
windows server 2003

this may be a red herring but I've searched and searched and searched for a solution.

Please help

Comment: what's the inner exception

Comment: on the screen shot - "syntax error near p0 on line 2."  have been unable to inspect the SQL but honestly it shouldn't matter. I can take a non working copy from the hard drive of one server and copy it to another and it will work...using the exact same files